# how to display multiple informations in single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my script, just i need help for display the name, vorname, titel, position and the date in one single pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(1,3):  
    url="https://portal.mvp.bafin.de/database/DealingsInfo/sucheForm.do?meldepflichtigerName=&zeitraum=0&emittentName=&d-5010980-p=" + str(i) + "&zeitraumVon=&emittentIsin=&meldepflichtigerButton=Suche+Meldepflichtiger&zeitraumBis="
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html5lib")
    table = soup.find("table", {"class":"displaytag"})
    tbody = table.find("tbody")
    for j in range(0, 20):
        tr = tbody.find_all("tr")[j]
        name = tr[0].iloc[0]
        vorname = tr[0].iloc[1]
        titel = tr[0].iloc[2]
        position = tr[0].iloc[3]
        date = tr[0].iloc[4]
```

Comment: Don't have enough time to check the web page, but pandas does have pandas.read_html() which may or may not help you.

Comment: i used it, but i can't access to a specific row or columns with pd.read_html()

Comment: try accessing specific rows and cols with ```.loc``` and ```.iloc``` after ```pd.read_html```

Comment: And please can you specify the problem you want to solve now in the question. Do you need to save ```tr,name...``` into dataframe as single row in the end of your loop or somethng else?

Comment: no, actually i'm trying to scrape a table in a web page, and i want to access to the first column which is of name because it contain a another url